# Inserting return before method causes VerifyError without message

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, javassist, javaagents

I've just tried to change a behavior of a method: replace the return value:

```java
ctMethod.insertBefore("return null;");
```

Transformation works perfectly, I even write `clazz.toBytecode()` to a file and IntelliJ IDEA decompiles that `.class` file successfully and I can see my change there.

However, there is a error that blocks retrasformation of the class, it seems it's thrown after my transformer is executed, it's in native code, and it doesn't have a message:

```
java.lang.VerifyError
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:167)
    at [place where I call retransformClasses]...
```

What does it mean? What am I doing wrong?

If I do `ctMethod.insertBefore("System.out.println(1);");` instead, it starts to work.

Version of javassist is `3.26.0-GA`. The same happens on `3.27.0-GA` and on `3.27.0-GA-bugfix-328`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setBody` (`ctMethod.setBody("return null;");`) solves the problem: now I have nulls returned.

Answer (score 2):

Your own answer mentions an alternative approach but does not answer your questions:

> What does it mean? What am I doing wrong?

Adding an unconditional `return` statement at the beginning of your question makes the rest of the method unreachable code. If you add such a statement in any Java class, compilation will fail with an **"unreachable statement"** error. Probably the byte code verifier also performs such a check.

---

**Update:** After some discussion and own research, I think that something can be done in Javassist in order to fix this problem, see [issue #352](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/352) which I have just created.

Comment: Unreachable code is possible in bytecode, with some precaution. However, here we have Javassist mixing source code concepts with bytecode manipulation and fails to produce valid bytecode. That’s the price of the concept, to allow developers to do bytecode manipulation without understanding bytecode.

Comment: It would be interesting to qualify "some precaution" a bit, because it might be worth talking about it with the Javassist maintainer. Maybe he can improve the tool a bit there. A few months ago he did fix a related bug for me when I generated a conditional `if (foo) return;` statement at the beginning of a constructor, which now works fine. Here the statement is unconditional. I am not a byte code expert like you, @Holger. So please shed some light on the situation, that would be interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @SerVB, can you try using Javassist 3.27-GA instead of 3.26-GA? It contains the fix I just remembered. I am not sure if it also affects methods - constructors like in my case are a bit special, e.g. with regard to "uninitialised this" - but it is worth a try. Just quickly try your old approach with `insertBefore` again, would you? Thanks.

Comment: @kriegaex , OK, will try with the up-to-date version and update the post.

Comment: The verifier requires a stackmap table entry describing the stack frame state at the beginning of the unreachable code. Since the state at the method entry is implied, just having local variables for `this` and each parameter, the code generator would first have to materialize an equivalent stack frame entry, then shift it by the inserted code. Javassist would have to do a similar thing for condition branches, e.g. `insertBefore("if(Math.random() < 1) System.out.println();")` needs an entry after the statement. Perhaps, it handles `insertBefore("if(Math.random() < 1) return null;")` correctly.

Comment: This sounds somewhat similar to the my fixed [issue #328](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/328), missing stackmap generation in some cases. And sorry, I remember wrong about the fix having been released in 3.27, it is still unreleased. But I am using my own temporary Javassist release, see [this comment](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/328#issuecomment-657926463). The Maven coordinates are `de.scrum-master.org.javassist:javassist:3.27.0-GA-bugfix-328`. @SerVB, this is the version you could test, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @SerVB, any findings with my bugfix version?

Comment: @kriegaex, oh, it was long ago and I don't remember details, but I see I've updated the post: "The same happens on 3.27.0-GA and on 3.27.0-GA-bugfix-328"

Comment: Um, well, I had not expected the information in a question update but rather in a comment. I am also not getting notifications for updated questions. But thanks. Did you file a new bug report for Javassist?

Comment: Nope. AFAIU, it's expected behavior, isn't it? Anyway, I think I won't open it until I bump into this problem again

Comment: @Holger's comments rather make me think that what you want should be possible and that there is a Javassist shortcoming in this situation. I have not used JA for a while, maybe I can look into it when I have a few cycles to spend.

Comment: **Update:** I think that something can be done in Javassist in order to fix this problem, see [issue #352](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/352) which I have just created.